# Confirmar se usuario ja foi registado VB

Tags: visual-basic-6

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicaçao em Visual Basic, em que eu insiro os registos para uma base de dados em sql server, esses registos sao mostrados no formulario ao utilizador numa datagridview, e eu quero confirmar se o registo ja esta efetuado ou nao, ou seija, se os campos que o utilizador insere ja se encontram na datagridview, especialmente o campo id que e a minha chave primaria!

Aguardo resposta! Cumprimentos

Comment: É **Visual Basic** ou **Visual Basic.NET**? Tenha em mente que as duas são linguagens muito diferentes. Como você fala de `datagrid`, provavelmente esteja se referindo a VB.NET. Aliás, você precisa especificar melhor seu problema, do jeito que está a sua pergunta pode ser considerada como **não clara o suficiente** e, provavelmente, será fechada. Clicando em [edit] você pode melhorar sua pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Vc pode encapsular seu método dentro de uma instrução try catch https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/fk6t46tz.aspx para saber se ocorreu algum erro.

Caso vc tenha criado o campo ID como IDENTITY pode usar a instrução sql para recuperar o código:

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('TABELA');
```